# A* vs D* vs Dijkstra

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, regression, searching

I understand the basis of A* as being a derivative of Dijkstra, however, I recently found out about D*.  From wikipedia, I can understand the algorithm.  What I do not understand is why I would use D* over Dijkstra.  To my understanding, Dijkstra gives a best path and D* works backwards from the end goal, but unlike A* it seems to do many calculations, so it doesn't seem as efficient.

Comment: This belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, it should go to [cs.SE]

Comment: okay i thought it was relevant here as I am interested in the algorithms ability to find the path.  I am working on the assumption that D* is not equal to Dijkstra but I dont understand what the algorithm really does, since i cant find much information on it.   I see the last sentence about efficient can be related to computer science.  So I will post there instead

Comment: This may be a math question, but it is incomprehensible because it uses unexplained notation, viz., $A^*$ and $D^*$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Its not notation, its the name of the algorithm.

Comment: It's notation for an algorithm, and unexplained.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Which algorithm is it notation for?

Comment: If I knew the answer to that one, 1938107, I wouldn't be raising such a fuss about it. Look, I'm trying to decide whether your question is about math, or about computing. You could make that easier for me (and others) by telling me what you mean by A* and D* (and editing same into the body of your question), or you could make it hard by playing games with names versus notations. But why would you want to make it hard for people to understand a question you want answered?

Comment: @GerryMyerson And i have been trying to tell you that is the name of the algorithm not the notation.

Comment: And I have been trying to get you to tell us, what is the algorithm whose name is A*? and what is the algorithm whose name is D*? But it's like pulling teeth, trying to get any useful information out of you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson A* is the name of the algorithm.  I can't be any more clear about that.  Type A* into google.  Are you saying I should put the entire algorithm into the question?

Comment: I'm saying if you want people to answer your question, you should do everything in your power to make it easier for them to do so.